# How to be notified before a xulrunner restart?

Tags: xul, xulrunner

I'm using the Xulrunner Extensions Manager in my desktop application, and I would like to be notified before a restart. Is there a way?

(the window's onclose() methods will not work..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add observers for the `"quit-application-requested"` or the `"quit-application"` notifications. The data parameter will be `"restart"` if this is a restart rather than a shutdown. (The notifications differ as to what the data parameter is for a shutdown; `"quit-application-requested"` passes `null` while `"quit-application"` passes `"shutdown"`.)